# Using Premiere's essential graphics panel to create a typewriter effect

Tags: premiere, after-effects, cc-2017

Is there a way to create a type-on typewriter effect using the Essential Graphics Panel in Premiere 2017 that does **not** require the user to manually keyframe each letter?

This tutorial shows that method:

But I'm wondering if there's a method more akin to an After Effects typewriter preset, where you set the source text, then reveal each character over time, character by character, or word by word (not unmasking pixel by pixel).

Thanks